# eject command not found in create-react-app -- how to add to package.json?

Tags: create-react-app, package.json

I get this error after installing create-react-app, and trying to run "npm run eject"

> eject: command not found.

How do I edit package.json to run the command I found in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `npm` try with `npx`

```
npx react-scripts eject
```

Above command worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around: run the script, manually, found in node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/eject.js.

> node ./node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/eject.js

Answer (score 1):

facebook's github indicates that the global install of create-react-app would interfere with CRA installation; and so I ran:

```
npm rm -g create-react-app
```

as suggested on facebook's github here:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088#issuecomment-562189517

(and then reinstall CRA)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install

https://github.com/ramyareye/react-native-eject

```
yarn add react-native-eject
yarn react-native eject
```